# How to deploy an android app to azure cloud?

Tags: android, azure, backend

I am new to azure and android programming. I developed an app using android, the app accepts a input (Text) from the user and Displays it in the Textview box, I also made an app service on azure.

I am looking for a way to send that text (entered by the user) to azure, and get some feedback (a simple text) from the cloud displayed in the Textview box. (Without using .NET technology)

All the tutorials that I found are focused on the TodoItem table and app.

Since, I am new to this technology, I would appreciate all the help I can get to learn how to deploy any android app, In other words communicate with azure.

**PS:** My question might be Ambiguous, however, this is the best way to explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways you can do this - and you don't have to use .NET :)

From your description of what you want to do, I would start with Azure Functions.

It's a serverless offering, so you won't have to worry about a ton of infrastructure and you can set a Function up so it responds to standard HTTP verbs (GET, POST, etc.)

Here is some documentation on [Azure Functions in general](https://msou.co/be8)

And Functions written in [Java in particular](https://msou.co/be7)  *(note that you do need to install .NET Core tooling, but you won't actually have to write any .NET code).*

Once you have a Function written and deployed to Azure, it will get a URL which your Android app can invoke. Once the Android app invokes it, the Function will run and return a response.

You are not deploying the Android app itself to Azure. Rather the Android app is only invoking an Azure Function via HTTP, and then making use of the return.

Follow the documentation on creating an HTTP Function with Java, then deploy it, then proceed to consume just like any other web/REST service.

Comment: _Thanks a lot Matt, this information was super helpful, I appreciate it._

Comment: No problem Mohamad - I'm glad it helped! If you wouldn't mind, would you mark the answer as accepted? Thanks!